# True isomorphisms in Haskell

Tags: haskell, isomorphism, coerce, derivingvia

Are the following assertions true:

1. The only real isomorphism, accessible programatically to the user, verified by Haskell type system, and that the Haskell compiler is/can be made aware of, is between:

   - the **set** of values of a Haskell datatype
   - the set of values of types those required by its constructors
2. Even generic programming can't produce "true" isomorphism, whose composition results at run time in an identity (thus [staged-sop](https://mpickering.github.io/papers/staged-sop.pdf) - and [similarly](https://yallop.github.io/metaocaml-syb/staging-generic-programming.pdf) in Ocaml)
3. Haskell itself is the only producing isomorphism, `Coercible`, but those isomorphism are restricted to the *identity* isomorphism

By "real isomorphism, accessible programatically to the user, verified by Haskell type system, and that the Haskell compiler is/can be made aware of" I mean a pair of function `u : a -> b` and `v : b -> a` such that *Haskell knows* (by being informed or otherwise) that `u.v=id` and `v.u=id`. Just like it knows (at compile time) how to rewrite some code to do "fold fusion", which is akin to, at once, recognize and apply it.

Comment: There are plenty of isomorphisms that are not the identity at runtime. E.g. `\case {True -> Left (); False -> Right ()}`. Why would these be not "true" isomorphisms?

Comment: It would help a lot if you provided some concrete examples of both real isomorphisms and things that are not real isomorphisms but are similar in some respect.

Comment: because they are not provably so. It's only because of some internal optimisation

Comment: @leftaroundabout from haskell perspective, this is just a ordinary function `Bool -> Either () ()`. it has no idea that it is actually an isomorphism. it can't exploit that fact. although I hope (?) it later on triggers some rewrite rules somewhere inside the compiler to no-op its composition with its inverse (maybe). aka it spots, generates, and apply the said isomophism

Comment: Well, nothing is really _provable_ in Haskell because of ⊥. If it's enough to _express_ the isomorphism with a type, then lens' [`Iso`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-5.1/docs/Control-Lens-Combinators.html#t:Iso) is an option, or you could make a custom `Category` instance wrapping the back- and forth mappings.

Comment: You can't express the isomorphism. it's just a pair of function that, in your head, are isomorphic. They (hopefully) will be recognized as isomorphic by some backdoor rewrite rule. bottom is another issue I think

Comment: Haskell is not a proof system, you generally don't write proofs in it. If a type is a semigroup, for example, you can express that by creating a Semigroup instance, but Haskell cannot check that the instance is lawful. Isomorphism of two types is no different.

Comment: @n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m. indeed it is not. I don't expect haskell to generate proofs. Although it could (like it does for coercible) (or internally with fold fusion etc..)

Comment: What aspect of this are you primarily interested in: (1) being able to express the concept of an isomorphism, so you can program with that concept, or (2) the compiler being able to use the isomorphism to make decisions about how to transform/optimise your code?

Comment: "Proofs" for Coercible are all trivial and can be generated mechanically. Proofs of isomorphism in general are not, and can not.

Comment: @Ben Coercible is not just for the compiler. it actually cuts code.

Comment: @n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m. they are generated mechanically, but they are not trivial, imo. Where I agree is that many more could be generated.

Comment: @nicolas I didn't claim that it was? I'm genuinely asking which angle you would like an answer to address; I was not making a statement of any kind about `Coercible`.

Comment: @Ben `Coercible` was just an example that it does not need to fall in 1 or 2. I would be interested in using 1 (programming with the concept of isomorphism) with 2 (real isomorphisms), and using the result of 1 to feed 2. real isomorphisms, recognized as such by the compiler.

Comment: One type is coercible to another iff the two types have the same representation. It is trivial to look at the representations and decide whether they are the same.

Comment: What would be some practical consequences of the compiler recognising isomorphisms as such?

Comment: @n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m.
once you know precisely what it means it is easy. cf https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/wikis/roles "Is (Int, String) representationally equivalent to (String, Int)? ". Then you need to thread that through the type system to make it surface in a consistent way with the user language (nominal, gadt and stuff). then you need to know what happens with higher order contraints (https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/issues/9123). etc.. It *should* be simple, that's for sure ! in the end, representations can (?) always be built with polynomial ho functors (?)

Comment: It's an interesting read but I don't think "isomorphism" per se is a useful notion here. Two types are isomorphic iff their cardinality is the same, but this is not useful at all. You probably want some kind of *canonical* isomorphism or something.

Answer (score 4):

Look into [Homotopy Type Theory](https://homotopytypetheory.org/book/)/[Cubical Agda](https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.6.0/language/cubical.html) where an "equality is isomorphism". I am not familiar enough with it to know what happens operationally, even if Agda knows isomorphic types are equal I still think your "true isomorphism" (i.e. with a proof and fusion) is too tall of an order.

In GHC it is possible to derive via "isomorphisms" but we need to wait for dependent types to properly verify isomorphisms in the type system. Even so they can be used to produce *bone fide* code even if you have to do some work operationally.

---

You already mentioned "representational equality" (`Coercible`) but it is worth discussing it. It underpins the two `coerce`-based deriving strategies: `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` and `DerivingVia` which generalizes GND.

GND is the simplest way to turn an isomorphism (`Coercible USD Int`) into code:

```
type    USD :: Type
newtype USD = MkUSD Int
  deriving
  newtype (Eq, Ord, Show, Num)
```

Operationally `coerce` is *zero-cost* at so they incur no cost at run-time. This is the only way you will get what you want in Haskell.

---

Isomorphisms can also be done through user-defined type classes.

An instance of [`Representable f`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/adjunctions-4.4/docs/Data-Functor-Rep.html) means `f` is (naturally) isomorphic to functions from its representing object `(Rep f ->)`. The [newtype `Co`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/adjunctions-4.4/docs/Data-Functor-Rep.html#t:Co) uses this isomorphism to derive function instances for representable functor. A `Pair a` of two values is represented by `Bool`, and is thus isomorphic to `Bool -> a`.

This isomorphism lets `Pair` derive `Functor`, `Applicative` and `Monad` by roundtripping through `(Bool ->)`:

```
type Pair :: Type -> Type
data Pair a = a :# a
  deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad)
  via Co Pair

instance Distributive Pair where
  distribute :: Functor f => f (Pair a) -> Pair (f a)
  distribute = distributeRep

instance Representable Pair where
  type Rep Pair = Bool

  index :: Pair a -> (Bool -> a)
  index (false :# true) = \case
    False -> false
    True  -> true

  tabulate :: (Bool -> a) -> Pair a
  tabulate make = make False :# make True
```

---

When you derive `Generic`/`Generic1` the compiler generates an isomorphism between a generic type and its generic representation `Rep`/`Rep1` (not to be confused with the representing object `Rep` from the above example).

The class laws state that `to`/`from` and `to1`/`from1` witness that isomorphism. The type system does not enforce these laws but if you derive them they should hold.

They are the main way to define generic implementations in Haskell. I recently introduced two newtypes `Generically` and `Generically1` to *base*, as standard names for generic behaviour (use [*generic-data*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-data) until the next GHC release). You can derive a generic isomorphism and programmatically use it in the next line without leaving the `data` declaration:

```
type Lists :: Type -> Type
data Lists a = Lists [a] [a] [a]
  deriving
  stock (Show, Generic, Generic1)

  deriving (Semigroup, Monoid)
  via Generically (Lists a)

  deriving (Functor, Applicative, Alternative)
  via Generically1 Lists
```

```
>> mempty @(Lists _)
Lists [] [] []
>> empty @Lists
Lists [] [] []
>> Lists "a" "b" "c" <> Lists "!" "." "?"
Lists "a!" "b." "c?"
>> pure @Lists 'a'
Lists "a" "a" "a"
```

You will however have to pay for the converstion cost, it's not as simple as adding `{-# Rules "to/from" to . from = id #-}` because the actual instances will appear with intermediate terms like `to (from a <> from b)`. Even your "true isomorphisms" GHC could not fuse away the conversion since it's not of the form `to . from`.

---

There is also a library [`iso-deriving`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/iso-deriving) ([blog](https://www.tweag.io/blog/2020-04-23-deriving-isomorphically/)) that allows deriving via arbitrary isomorphisms.

Comment: I wish there was something between full homotopy type theory, which is a very general solution, and `coerce` as it is now, which is extremely specific. as far as I can tell, tracking identity merely means a compiler can cut through his own weight. which is great from one point of view (and no small feat). from another is really just the *minimum* you can expect of a type system: if you just use it to generate names, the newtype,  not bothering about representation, "of course" it should allow you to swap names between the name *he* created and *his* wrapped name